# Refactor rails codes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I've tried to make this shorter, but CodeClimate (code reviewer) always says that there are still some duplications and complexities.

so far, this is what I have after an attempt to refactor it.

These are API codes for my app:

```
class CallbackController < ApplicationController
  def gmail
    unless params[:error].present?
      code = current_user.tokens.for(:gmail).create(:hash_key => params[:code], :hash_type => "code")

      response = API::Gmail.new(gmail_callback_index_url).generate_tokens(params[:code])

      if response['error'].present?
        current_user.tokens.for(:gmail).using(:code).destroy_all
        redirect_to(network_path(current_user.network), alert: "Authentication failed. Invalid request.")
      else
        access_token = current_user.tokens.for(:gmail).create(:hash_key => response['access_token'], :hash_type => "access_token", :primary => true)
        id_token = current_user.tokens.for(:gmail).create(:hash_key => response['id_token'], :hash_type => "id_token")
        refresh_token = current_user.tokens.for(:gmail).create(:hash_key => response['refresh_token'], :hash_type => "refresh_token")
        Resque.enqueue(Jobs::Gmail::Today, current_user.id)
        redirect_to network_path(current_user.network), notice: "GMail Access granted."
      end
    else
      redirect_to network_path(current_user.network), alert: "GMail Access denied."
    end
  end

  def googlecalendar
    unless params[:error].present?
      code = current_user.tokens.for(:googlecalendar).create(:hash_key => params[:code], :hash_type => "code")

      response = API::Googlecalendar.new(googlecalendar_callback_index_url).generate_tokens(params[:code])

      if response['error'].present?
        current_user.tokens.for(:googlecalendar).using(:code).destroy_all
        redirect_to(network_path(current_user.network), alert: "Authentication failed. Invalid request.")
      else
        access_token = current_user.tokens.for(:googlecalendar).create(:hash_key => response['access_token'], :hash_type => "access_token", :primary => true)
        id_token = current_user.tokens.for(:googlecalendar).create(:hash_key => response['id_token'], :hash_type => "id_token")
        refresh_token = current_user.tokens.for(:googlecalendar).create(:hash_key => response['refresh_token'], :hash_type => "refresh_token")
        #Resque.enqueue(Jobs::Googlecalendar::Today, current_user.id)
        redirect_to network_path(current_user.network), notice: "Google Calendar Access granted."
      end
    else
      redirect_to network_path(current_user.network), alert: "Google Calendar Access denied."
    end
  end

  def yammer
    unless params[:error].present?
      code = current_user.tokens.for(:yammer).create(:hash_key => params[:code], :hash_type => "code")

      response =  API::Yammer.new.generate_tokens(params[:code])

      if response['error'].present?
        current_user.tokens.for(:yammer).using(:code).destroy_all
        redirect_to network_path(current_user.network), alert: "Authentication failed. Invalid request."
      else
        access_token = current_user.tokens.for(:yammer).create(:hash_key => response['access_token']['token'], :hash_type => "access_token", :primary => true)
        Resque.enqueue(Jobs::Yammer::Latest, current_user.id)
        redirect_to network_path(current_user.network), notice: "Yammer Access granted."  
      end      
    else
      redirect_to network_path(current_user.network), alert: "Yammer Access denied."
    end
  end
end
```

Any workarounds, tips, recommendations on how to make it shorter and logically not duplicated will be appreciated.

UPDATE:

Tried to put a before_filter but no luck. I guess there should be a way to limit duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-factor this as follow,

create another module in lib as callback_helper.rb

```
module CallbackHelper

    [:gmail, :googlecalendar, :yammer].each do |callback_method|
        define_method("#{callback_method}") do 
            unless params[:error].present?
              code = current_user.tokens.for(callback_method).create(:hash_key => params[:code], :hash_type => "code")

              response =  "API::#{callback_method.to_s.capitalize}".constantize.new.generate_tokens(params[:code])

              if response['error'].present?
                current_user.tokens.for(callback_method).using(:code).destroy_all
                redirect_to network_path(current_user.network), alert: "Authentication failed. Invalid request."
              else
                access_token = current_user.tokens.for(callback_method).create(:hash_key => response['access_token']['token'], :hash_type => "access_token", :primary => true)
                Resque.enqueue("Jobs::#{callback_method.to_s.capitalize}::Today".constantize, current_user.id)
                redirect_to network_path(current_user.network), notice: "#{callback_method} Access granted."  
              end      
            else
              redirect_to network_path(current_user.network), alert: "#{callback_method} Access denied."
            end
        end
    end
end
```

include this in your callback controller as

```
  include CallbackHelper
```

Now your controller have access to all method defined by your module.

Make sure new module is auto loaded. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the method. Well appreciated :)